# How can I get the error text in django?

Tags: django, django-errors

I want to get the exception text when I save value into the database.

view.py:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = CustomerForm(request.POST)        

    if form.is_valid():
        try:
            customer = form.save(commit=False)           
            customer.save()
        except DatabaseError:
            message = 'Database Error: ' + str(??? text error ???)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a 2nd variable on the `except` statement. It will hold the text error. See below

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = CustomerForm(request.POST)        

    if form.is_valid():
        try:
            customer = form.save(commit=False)           
            customer.save()
        except DatabaseError, text_error:
            message = u'Database Error: {0}'.format(text_error)
```

Comment: @VadimKiselev  u can put Exception into a object and can print extra info too.see my answer

Comment: correct the text_error is not a string. I've fixed my answer

Answer (score -1):

You can print exception as given below.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = CustomerForm(request.POST)
```

`if form.is_valid():
    try:
        customer = form.save(commit=False)           
        customer.save()
    except DatabaseError as e:
        message = 'Database Error: ' + str(e.message)`

Comment: it will work u can check type(e.message) is str .
type(e.message)
<type 'str'>

Comment: @ Prashant Gaur Without str error message is not visible. In my template:    <script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('.btn-success').click(function(){

          $.post("", { },
          function(data, status)
          {
            alert("Warning!\n\n" + data['message']);
          })
      
          .fail(function() { alert("Error"); });
          return false;
      });
    }); 
    </script>

Comment: i tried this on python console and there it was working . i have edited my answer as per your explanation.  thanks